# There is no pending application request

Tags: facebook, request, fbml

Whenever i receive a developer request to work on a app i can see the request in: https://developers.facebook.com/apps?view=app_requests

but whenever i accept it says "There is no pending application request"

if i go back to https://developers.facebook.com/apps?view=app_requests the requests are still there. but no authorised apps to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug report for it:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/175135269278145?browse=search_50190b6ea18403606695980